# Нужна ли запятая: "...найдется(,) чему здесь позавидовать"?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая в предложении:

**Многим субъектам РФ найдется, чему здесь позавидовать.**

Answer (score 3):

Многим субъектам РФ найдется, **чему здесь позавидовать**.  Сравнить: Здесь **есть чему позавидовать.**

Это тема называется "Цельные по смыслу выражения и их отличие от придаточных предложений". [Розенталь. § 41. Цельные по смыслу выражения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146#pp146)

Цельный фразеологический оборот  эквивалентен члену предложения, но если  **словосочетание утрачивает фразеологическую цельность**, то оно приравнивается к придаточному предложению  и выделяется запятой.

Думаю, что в данном случае наречие "здесь" меняет статус оборота, и его структура требует интонационного выделения.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая нужна, она отделяет главное предложение от придаточного.